# What is the difference between $\prod\limits_{i=1}^L \mathbb{R}^{k_i}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\prod\limits_{i=1}^L k_i} $?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, vector-spaces

I understand that the former is an $L$ tuple which contains vectors of length $k_i$ in the $i$th position.
Is the latter a $L$-dimensional matrix with $k_i$ entries in the $i$th  dimension?

I believe a simple bijection exists between these two spaces making them equivalent in some way (perhaps the word is isomorphic?). Is there a time we would want to refer to one vs the other?

In the problem I'm trying to solve, I have $b_i \in \mathbb{R}^{k_i}$. I want to define an object $B$ that contains all of the $b_i$. Does it make more sense to define $B$ in one space than the other? Could I define it either way? I find the latter space a bit perplexing.

Comment: There is a natural vector space isomorphism between $\prod_{i=1}^L \mathbb{R}^{k_i}$ and $$\mathbb{R}^{\sum_{i=1}^L k_i}$$ This gives an easier comparison to the latter space you mention.

Comment: Thanks. For the isomorphic spaces you've mentioned, when would you refer to one vs the other?

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty simple: $\enspace\prod\limits_{i=1}^L \mathbf{R}^{k_i}$ is $\;\mathbf R^{\textstyle\sum_{i=1}^Lk_i}$.

Answer (score 0):

If we consider a special case of the latter space as $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 4}$ (a 2-dimensional matrix). That would have 12 entries, whereas the object you are describing should only have 7.
So the two spaces are not equivalent and the space you want is the former $\prod\limits_{i=1}^L \mathbb{R}^{k_i}$.